# concatenar nombres laravel guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Recibo el nombre del usuario logeado con el siguiente codigo:

```
{{ Auth::guard('profesor')->user()->nombre }}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero concatenar con el apellido, como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debería poderse solucionar con accessors en el modelo:

```
public function getNombreCompletoAttribute()
{
   return $this->nombre . ' ' . $this->apellido;
}
```

y lo llamas en la vista:

```
{{ Auth::guard('profesor')->user()->nombre_completo }}
```

Ver más información en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor